# Can't browse internet, but ping working

Tags: 14.04, wireless, internet

I am using a dell latitude E5440 with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The WiFi suddenly stopped working today.

I tried pinging a few ip addresses and ping works fine, but pinging any URL does not.

Seems to be a DNS issue, but I didn't touch anything like that. What is wrong here?

Comment: You tried rebooting?

Comment: Yep..the laptop..the router..enable/disable networking & wifi

Comment: Try `sudo dhclient -r` then `sudo dhclient`

Comment: I believe the second command was sudo dhclient (without a -) , release worked fine..but the second command does not return

Comment: That - near the second one isn't part of the command. It's the separator for my name.

Comment: Sorry about that...ne hints from the info. Above?

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: Sudo dhclient -r ran successfully.. Sudo dhclient didn't respond for long..

Comment: You need to give it a while. It takes a minute.

Comment: Yeah..it says.."RTNETLINK answers: File exists"

Comment: I guess look that up. I can't currently.

Comment: I had to mark the wireless interface down..flush ip addresses ..mark it back up..then tried the dhclient commands..that did it :) .. If you could explain the issue and solve in an answer it would be great!

Comment: Would you be able to give me the source link for that? You could also answer your own question if you like ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33843/discussion-between-nikel-and-zacharee1).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks to [zacharee1](https://askubuntu.com/users/274320/zacharee1), had to release and renew ip addresses. Also had to flush ip addresses :

```
sudo ip link set wlan0 down 
sudo ip addr flush wlan0 
sudo ip link set wlan0 up
sudo dhclient -r
sudo dhclient
```

Comment: @zacharee1 : I am pretty much ending up doing this once in every 1 or 2 days. Any idea why it keeps happening again and again?

Comment: @zacharee1, I've been having a similar issue that this solution works for. As nikel experienced, the problem resurfaces every few days. How can I effect a permanent fix? I'm running 16.04.1 (xenial)

Comment: As expected, failed with my wifi connecion with authentication certificate.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing exactly the same issue, it's fairly obvious that's something related with the DNS and I finally solved adding the DNS servers of this way:

```
sudo vim /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail
```

write the DNS servers in the file:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Restart the NetworkManager service:

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service
```

That's it!
Try this...Thank me later!