# Suddenly, www.google.com cannot be browsed, but ping is ok

Tags: firefox, dns, proxy

Suddenly, www.google.com cannot be browsed, but ping is ok. I can still open it from my Android phone and other computers on the same network, so I think it is a local problem. I can open any other sites, while I noticed that internet become slow.

When I try to open google.com from Firefox I get this message:

> Secure Connection Failed
>
> The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading. The
>   page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity
>   of the received data could not be verified. Please contact the website
>   owners to inform them of this problem.

I tried to clear cache, history and offline sites data with no success.

I tried solutions from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717029/cant-browse-internet-but-ping-working), but they didn't help either.

Comment: It could be because of your date time settings. Set your date and time to the date and time of your current time zone if its wrong.

Comment: You could try [refreshing Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings). Unless other web browsers are affected.

Comment: Chromium web browser is affected too.

Comment: Date and Time and Time zone are not changed.

Comment: You've tried rebooting?