# Ubuntu 20.04 network no longer working

Tags: networking, internet

Yesterday the internet wasn't reachable. Firefox wasn't working, in terminal I tried `links2 www.cnn.com` and it wasn't working either; I tried `dig <somesite>` and it was working; I also tried with a wifi dongle.
As it comes out of nothing when I turned on the PC, in the mmid-morning the problem went away and everything worked in regular way. I though it was over but today is even worse.
I tried

- unplug the eth cable and plug it again
- using the USB dongle (already used in the past) to connect via wifi
- links2 in terminal
- changed the DNS from OpenDNS to the Google one
- changed from "DHCP" to "manual" in the connection parameters in network setting
- reset the router

To check if was just my user or the entire system i logged as my sister's user and verified that user can't use internet, too.

As a final test I started windows which is in dual boot on the same machine, that means the averything is the same in ubuntu. It worked! I'm using it to write now.

I haven't changed nothing in the last two days (14 oct 2021); for what I remeber, where was an automatic update of the network stuff and of the entire kernel.

Am I the only one facing this issue?

Any suggestion to investigate what is going wrong?

Thank in advance

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`. Read https://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: nothing worse than a -ve rating without any reason, especially when you are a new user. it is kinda disgusting how humans are.
So removed the -ve.

Answer (score 3):

I thought the problem was over, but, sadly, this morning I can't use internet. :(

I looked in the shell's history and retyped some of yesterday's command

```
sudo ip link set enp3s0 down

sudo ip adrr flush enp3s0 

sudo ip link set enp3s0 up

sudo dhclient -r

sudo dhclient
```

Just changes the port name from [post in askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717029/cant-browse-internet-but-ping-working)

and now I'm online again. :-)

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED (I believe, I haven't rebooted, yet)

I removed the PIA VPN autostart at boot, and everything looks ok: I'm writing with linux, now.

---------- EDIT/UPDATE -----------------------

I was planning to complain with PIA - after all I lost two days - but I checked that I have ver 1.28 and the 1.3 was available; after the upgrade even with VPN on there wasn't (isn't) any problem.

Comment: There isn't so much to add. The problem was due to the VPN software.

Comment: There isn't so much to add. **The problem was due to the VPN software.**
As first step I disabled the VPN, then -before complaining with PIA, luckly- I got I was running the version 1.28 of PIA's software; I upgraded to 1.3 and now the network is OK even with the VPN on.

Comment: Please [edit] and put additional info in your answer, not in the comments.

Comment: I edited the post yesterday, it already says the same things the comment does. I don't see what else I can add.